# MPMoviePlayerController do not load movie

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play video in my iPad app, using MPMoviePlayerController. My problem is, that player is only displaying "Loading" and do not play the video. Here is the code I use:

```
- (void)playMovieFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *fileUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileUrl];
    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.frame];

    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

I also try to use MPMoviePlayerViewController, but with sane success.Also, what movie types do MPMoviePlayerController plays? Can it be because of size of movie? It is 263 MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie formats supported on the iPhone are `.mov, .m4v, mp4 or 3gp`.

[The video technologies in iOS support the playback of movie files with the .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp filename extensions and using the following compression standards:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html)

In Case you playing the movie with above mentioned extensions then. declare your MPMoivePlayer as class type property in your `.h` class

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

in your `.m`

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"mov"];

NSURL *fileUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileUrl];
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];

[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: Now, I've tried with other .mov video, but it do not load again. Also, is there any other frameworks to play movies?

Comment: Make sure you are giving the right path for the movie and also if you are playing .mov then it should be .mov type. Also try `[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];`

Comment: Thanks very much, it is starts to work, but now I have another problem , player do not display any picture, it only plays sound.

Comment: If it is video then should show the video. try to play some other video

Comment: are you setting the frame for the player??? make sure you set the player big enough that it is visible on your screen. try to set the frame of player equal to your main view

Comment: I think, this is enough big!!

    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.frame];

Comment: Post your code in the question then, are you registering for notification also? when movie stops to play???

Comment: Edited. Also, can it be because of size of movie? It is 263 MB.

Comment: set the frame like this `[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];`

Comment: Same success. The player is visible, as it always was, but playing only sound. When real video is with picture.

Comment: Well try to play some small video and see if it gives the same results? secondly consult the MPMoviePlayerController apple docs page for finding about the size